# Wordpress query WHERE x = $x

Tags: php, wordpress

My query works fine with string but does not work when i put the var.

Any help woul'd be appreciated.

```
$title = get_the_title(); // in products search result loop
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM demos_13_amelia_users WHERE `status` = 'visible' AND `type` = 'provider' AND `firstName` = '.$title.'";
//type` = 'provider' AND `firstName` = 'Perry'";
$employes = $wpdb->get_results($query);
//print_r($employes);
```

Comment: Besides leaving yourself wide open for a sql injection attack, it looks fine to me. What's the value of `$title` once it gets to this point int the code? (Hoping it's not `0;DROP TABLE demos_13_amelia_users;--`)

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for replying.
$title = get_the_title(); // in products search result loop

Comment: You should always check `$wpdb->last_error` when you have an issue with wordpress queies.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assembling the query string correctly. In your example, if $title='Perry" the resulting string is:

```
SELECT * FROM demos_13_amelia_users WHERE `status` = 'visible' AND `type` = 'provider' AND `firstName` = '.Perry.'
```

You are inside double-quotes, so the variable will be resolved automatically and you don't need the dots for concatenation:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM demos_13_amelia_users WHERE `status` = 'visible' AND `type` = 'provider' AND `firstName` = '$title'";
```

If you want to use the dots, you need to close and reopen the quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM demos_13_amelia_users WHERE `status` = 'visible' AND `type` = 'provider' AND `firstName` = '" . $title . "'";
```

Comment: I have tried both syntaxes but i doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work". Are you getting an error? When, and what does it say? If you print the query, does it look correct?